# Error making a request in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using IndexedDB and I created this function where I just want to add a new object.

```
var request = indexedDB.open("db", 1);
request.onsuccess = function(event){
   request = event.target.result;
   var transaction = request.transaction(["cart"], "readwrite");
   var store = transaction.objectStore("cart");
   var obj = {
    w : w,
    x : x,
    y: y,
    z: z
   };
   var requestAdd = store.add(obj);
   requestAdd.onsuccess = function(w){
      console.log("great");         
   }
   request.close();
}
```

Here is how I create my indexes and the objectStore

```
var storeCart = db.createObjectStore("cart", { autoIncrement : true });
        storeCart.createIndex("w", "w", {unique: false});
        storeCart.createIndex("x", "x", {unique: false});
        storeCart.createIndex("y", "y", {unique: false});
        storeCart.createIndex("z", "z", {unique: false});
```

But, for some reason, when I tried to access `cart` I get this error:

```
NotFoundError: The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened.
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you need to create your objectStore and your indexes in the request.onupgradeneeded event.

To fire that event you need to create the indexedDB for the first time OR change the indexedDB version when calling `indexedDB.open()`:

```
// You need to change the DB version in order to
// fire the onupgradeneeded event (or delete the previous indexedDB)

var request = indexedDB.open("db", 2);

request.onsuccess = function(event){
     // your code
     // ...
}

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){

    var db = event.target.result;

    var storeCart = db.createObjectStore("cart", { autoIncrement : true });

    storeCart.createIndex("w", "w", {unique: false});
    storeCart.createIndex("x", "x", {unique: false});
    storeCart.createIndex("y", "y", {unique: false});
    storeCart.createIndex("z", "z", {unique: false});

}
```